# Lightweight ad-blocker for firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, performance, adblock

On a old machine (512 MB RAM) I am currently running ubuntu jaunty and firefox 3.0.15. I tried the ad blocker addon add block plus but it eats lots of RAM (>300 MB).

- Is high memory load of this add-on a bug, which is fixed in a newer version or just normal? If so, why is the memory usage so high?
- Is there another ad blocker add-on for firefox, another browser- add-on combination for linux (ubuntu jaunty) or even better a browser independent solution for linux which uses significant less RAM?

Comment: Please could you explain me why this question was closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABP acknowledges on their forum that they have a significant memory overhead, so if you want to get your RAM usage down you will have to switch to something else.

You could always try an ad-blocking HOSTS file, which wouldn't waste RAM. [This particular one](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) is regularly updated, but be sure to check it over before adopting it and make a backup of your original to be safe, of course. [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5817447/how-to-block-unwanted-ads-in-all-applications-and-speed-up-web-browsing-with-the-hosts-file) also has a whole article on this subject.

Comment: Can you provide a reference/link for the acknowledgement made by the ABP folks?

Comment: Further looking into the ABP forums shows a lot of performance optimization threads where IT-savvy folk have got their memory consumption cut down quite a bit. There is a lot of talk about this, the best "acknowledgment" I can find is here:  https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9741&p=57729&hilit=memory+overhead#p57729

Comment: @techie007 You can also look into the mercurial logs to see the comments on what the Dev has recently changed and updated. So I recommend everyone makes sure they have an up-to-date plugin to get these fixes in too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)

Example:

```
/etc/dnsmasq.d/malware.list<
address=/googlesyndication.com/0.0.0.0
```

blocks the ads for googlesyndication.com in every browser and app.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted...

Comment: This method can be applied in modified router firmware such as DD-WRT, but could adding many of those slow down the router?

Answer (score 0):

On can also use `privoxy` or `Bfilter`. For `privoxy` there is a script which converts adblock+ lists for privoxy, see: http://andrwe.org/scripting/bash/privoxy-blocklist, same for `Bfilter`: http://www.convoglio.com/bfilter/